# how should I set automatic launch of xfce4-terminals with 4 tabs with default working directory?

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, gnome-terminal, xfce

please see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65120595/is-there-any-way-i-can-open-multiple-terminals-on-the-xfce4-window-automatically/65127727#65127727

I could manage to automatically generat two xfce4-terminals each with 4 tabs. That is good.
But I want the left window have default working directory to ~/dir1 and the right window to ~/dir2. I don't know how to specify it.
The command I used is

> xfce4-terminal --default-working-directory="/home/$USER/dir1"
> --geometry="134x79+108+62" --tab --tab --tab

But this left window's 4 tabs are starting at my home directory not ~/dir1. How should I specify it? (I tried giving --command="cd ~/dir1" after the first --tab but it was in vain.  (ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a script and inserting a line with CD in it? (I'm just guessing here)

```
#!/bin/sh  
# ... This is a Script, save it with extension .sh  
# ... and mark it as executable: chmod +x ./path/script.sh  
# ... The advantage of scripts is that you can assign  
# ... keyboard hotkeys to initialize them.
YourCommand1  
cd /directory/you/want  
# ... always empty line at the end
```

Or maybe trying with `cd` BEFORE the command.

Comment: ok I'll try that at work when I'm at it.